# Sandwich rule for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm taking a first year calculus course and I'm stuck on a concept with sequences. The question asks to use the sandwich rule to find the following limits of sequences:

[image: sequence 1] (1)

and

[image: sequence 2] (2)

I've shown that (1) = 3 by factoring out 3^n to 3(1)^1/n, and that (2) = 0 as n! = n(n-1)(n-2)... and n^n = n.n.n... which is clearly larger. However, I have no idea how to apply the sandwich rule here. The way we've been taught is to use a simple case and build it up:
[image: example]

Can anyone give me a few examples on how to approach these types of questions, or other resources to turn to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $3 < (3^n+1)^{1/n} < 3\cdot 2^{1/n}$, and $0 < \dfrac{n!}{n^n} < \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thank you! All I'm confused about is the choice of the upper bound. The first one is clear, but for the second, why choose $1\over n$? That is, how do we know for sure that n!/n^n < 1/n?

Comment: $\dfrac{n!}{n^n} = \dfrac{1\cdot 2\cdots n}{n\cdot n\cdots n} < 1\cdot 1\cdots \dfrac{1}{n}$